# Extract coordinates from GeoJSON file in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to extract coordinates from a GeoJSON file . I tried this line of code but I didn't have result in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: '/area.geojson',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
    });

    function getCoordinatesOfCounties() {
        var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
        features.forEach((feature) => {
            var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            console.log(coordinates);
        });
    }
      
    </script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: The is no call of `getCoordinatesOfCounties` function in the above code. When did you call it? It should be called after `featuresloadend` event is triggered on the vector source.

Comment: @TomazicM I didn't  understand ! what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait till features are loaded into the source, then you can get coordinates of the features. You can use vector source event `featuresloadend` for that (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector.VectorSourceEvent.html).

Event `featuresloadend` is fired when all the features are loaded into the source. Property `evt.features` of event processing function parameter `evt` contains all the loaded features. For this to work you have to add vector layer to the map.

Code could the look something like this:

```
function getCoordinatesOfCounties(evt) {
  var features = evt.features;
  features.forEach((feature) => {
      var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      console.log(coordinates);
  });
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: '/area.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
vectorSource.on('featuresloadend', getCoordinatesOfCounties);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource;
});
map.addLyer(vectorLayer);
```

If you don't want to add layer to the map and just read features, you can use JS `fetch` to read data and `ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures` to read the features:

```
function getCoordinatesOfCounties(features) {
  features.forEach((feature) => {
      var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      console.log('coords', coordinates);
  });
}

function readFeatures(data) {
  var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
  getCoordinatesOfCounties(features);
}

fetch('/area.geojson')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {readFeatures(data)});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but even when I tried this , I didn't have a result on the console !@TomazicM

Comment: You have to add vector layer to the map for the features to be loaded into the source.

Comment: See modified answer.